# Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\cos\frac{\pi k}{2n}=\frac{2}{\pi}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Please help me to show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\cos\dfrac{\pi k}{2n}=\dfrac{2}{\pi}$$

I'm absolutely clueless.

A hint rather than a complete solution would be more appreciated!

Comment: **Hint**: Riemann sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

Answer (score 3):

There's another approach through trigonometrical manipulation.

Simplify
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(\alpha+k\beta)$$

There are two possible ways, so far as I know:

1. Since $\cos x=(\exp(ix)+\exp(-ix))/2$, we can regard $S$ as a linear combination of geometrical progressions.
2. Consider an identity $2\cos(\alpha+k\beta)\sin(\beta/2)=\sin(\alpha+(k+1/2)\beta)-\sin(\alpha+(k-1/2)\beta)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Riemann sum whose limit is an integral

$$\int_0^1 dx \: \cos{\left( \frac{\pi}{2} x \right )}$$